# Binding properties of nested entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view odel that wraps my entities.  It looks like this:

```
public class EmailTemplateViewModel
{
    public List<EmailAccount> EmailAccounts { get; set; }
    public EmailTemplate EmailTemplate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email Account")]
    public int EmailAccountId { get; set; }

}
```

The entity that I want to save on the postback is `EmailTemplate`.  `EmailAccount` is nested inside `EmailTemplate` but I make view model like this so I can build a drop down for user to select (I removed that code as it's not relevant).

In my controller, to get the email template I am binding like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "EmailAccountId, EmailTemplate")] EmailTemplateViewModel emailTemplateViewModel)
{

}
```

By defualt this binds every property of `EmailTenplate`.  If I don't want the view in question to be able to insert certain properties is there a way to specify certain properties on nested template to bind?

I tried:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "EmailAccountId, EmailTemplate.Property1, EmailTemplate.Property2")] EmailTemplateViewModel emailTemplateViewModel)
{

}
```

But that dosn't work.  Is there a feature of MVC that does this or must I explicitly add properties to the view model and then map them to nested entities myself in controller?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this:

```
[Bind(Exclude="EmailAccounts")]
public class EmailTemplateViewModel
{
    public List<EmailAccount> EmailAccounts { get; set; }
    public EmailTemplate EmailTemplate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email Account")]
    public int EmailAccountId { get; set; }
}

[Bind(Exclude="Property1,Property2")]
public class EmailTemplate
{
    public string Property1 {get;set;}
    public string Property2 {get;set;}
    public string Property3 {get;set;}
}
```